# Prognosis modelling data set

Tags: predictive-models, modeling, validation

I want to externally validate and update a previously developed and published model (Model A) in my dataset. In the case of poor performance, I would like to develop a new model for the same outcome (Model B). Can I use the same dataset to validate model A and then develop model B? Are there any guidelines regarding this?

Thank you!

Comment: Consider resampling-based validation.  Complete strategies are [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc).